# How to find regex that match only JOIN and not LEFT OUTER JOIN and INNER OUTER JOIN

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I am working on a problem where I need to find a reqex which matches only the word JOIN and not RIGHT OUTER JOIN or LEFT OUTER JOIN

So I want only to replace join and not LEFT OUTER JOIN or RIGHT OUTER JOIN in a senetence.

I am working to have a regex like this but I am stuck after this

> "REGEX_FIND_OUT" = ^((?!LEFT OUTER JOIN | RIGHT OUTER JOIN).)*$

```
System.out.println("dfdsfsdfds JOIN dsfsdfd LEFT OUTER JOIN dfdfgdg RIGHT OUTER JOINdsfsdf".replaceAll("REGEX_FIND_OUT", "replace"));
```

**Output should be**

```
"dfdsfsdfds replace dsfsdfd LEFT OUTER JOIN dfdfgdg RIGHT OUTER JOINdsfsdf"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`negative lookbehind`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

```
(?<!RIGHT OUTER\s)(?<!LEFT OUTER\s)JOIN
```

- `(?<!RIGHT OUTER\s)` - Should not be preceded by `RIGHT OUTER`
- `(?<!LEFT OUTER\s)` - Should not be preceded by `LEFT OUTER`
- `JOIN` - Matches `JOIN`

[`Demo`](https://regex101.com/r/TPpJNN/1/)